# Api for remote acess phone and send sms messages

Tags: php

I am developing an ecommerce using php

I would like to have notification system which send SMS to users cellphones about orders and other stuff. I know that one of the ways to achive this is to some api wich allow to send msgs from the internet. My problem is that im in angola and due to economic crisis here  its hard to get an credit card to pay things online. So my Idea is to use my phone personal data, I have an unlimited SMS plan, so is it possible to use an api which allows remote access to my phone sms text editor, where I can have the number, the  contents of the message and I use my phone sms plan to send the message.